# I want to change "postive_" to "negative_" throughout my code depending on a variables value

Tags: r

I have written some code that imports .Rda files and then uses the data loaded from the files in the code. The .Rda files are from a machine that runs in positive and negative mode, and this is reflected in the file names. THey both have the same file name but one file name will have positive in it and the other will have negative in it.  For example,
`B_positive_mode_fat_names.Rda`and `B_negative_mode_fat_names.Rda`. The variables loaded from each one will be 
`B.positive_mode_fat_names` and `B.negative_mode_fat_names` respectively. 
I am trying to use a variable called  `device mode` which i will put it equal to either positive or negative, and I want to code to change all the "positive_" to "negative_" if the device mode is negative, as i have written the code for negative. Is it possible to create an R script to go through the code and change all the "positive_" to "negative_".

```
device_mode <- negative
load("B_positive_mode_fat_names.Rda")
load("A_positive_mode_fat_names.Rda")
merged <- union(B.positive_mode_fat_names,A.positive_mode_fat_names)
```

For example with the above code, I would like the code to change the positive_ to negative_. The code in total is 600 lines long, and I would like to have one version instead of having a positive version and negative version of the code. Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Seems like what you need is "Find" and "Replace All" which is available in most of the editors and IDE's.

Comment: Rstudio does have find and replace. It would require me to have two versions of the code, one positive and one negative, thus when I make changes to one code I would have to copy it to the next one.

Comment: I think what you need is something like:
```device_mode <- "negative";
eval(parse(text=paste0("load(A_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda)")))```
or creating a function with argument the ```device_mode```

Comment: Hi NpT, I just realised that I had not included the speech marks within the brackets after load.

Comment: hi @NimaHojat the change is in the eval parse, i.e.: 
```eval(parse(text=paste0("load('A_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda')")))```

Comment: @NpT, why not to put your comment as an answer?

Comment: @VitaliAvagyan Thank you for your suggestion. I am not sure if this is what Nima required. If I get a positive feedback, I will do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to go:

1. use `eval(parse(text)))`. i.e:

   ```
   device_mode <- "negative"
   eval(parse(text=paste0("load('A_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda')")))
   eval(parse(text=paste0("load('B_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda')")))
   ```
2. create a function along with the eval-parse-text

   ```
   device_mode <- "negative"
   myFun<-function(device_mode){
     eval(parse(text=paste0("load('A_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda')")))
     eval(parse(text=paste0("load('B_",device_mode,"_mode_fat_names.Rda')")))
     # do other stuff also
   }
   results<-myFun(device_mode)
   ```